# AngularJS - Passing a function from a parent to a child's class controller through binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, parent-child

I'm using AngularJS 1.7 and basing my code on the following Todd Motto style guide: https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide

I want to pass a function from my parent component to a child one through binding, I get a function if I console.log it but I can't seem to be able to call it on the controller.

Here is my code:

**parent.html**

```html
<child functionToRun="$ctrl.print(message)"></child>
```

**parentController.js**

```js
export class ParentController {
  contructor($log) {
    'ngInject';
    this.$log = $log;
  }

  print(message) {
    console.log(message);
  }
}
```

**child.component.js**

```js
import { ChildController } from './child.controller';
import templateUrl from './child.html';

export const ChildComponent = {
    templateUrl,
    controller: ChildController,
    bindings: {
        functionToRun: '&'
    }
};
```

**childController.js**

```js
export class ChildController {
  constructor() {
    'ngInject';
  }

  $onInit() {
    this.functionToRun.call(this, 'hello');
  }
}
```

I've searched for a similar question but couldn't find any, sorry if there is already one.

Is this possible? (I want to call it on the controller, not on the HTML-$scope)

If so can you tell me my error? 
Thanks, appreciate it

Comment: Try passing it in like: `<child function-to-run="$ctrl.print(message)"></child>`

Comment: Also, the child might need to call it with an object, like `this.functionToRun({ message: 'hello' })`

Comment: thank you so much @FrankModica! it worked, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the function in using hyphens, like this:

```
<child function-to-run="$ctrl.print(message)"></child>
```

Then call the function with an object:

```
this.functionToRun({ message: 'hello' });
```